# Treating hexadecimal as an integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In a Ruby on Rails app, we have some details which are stored as an Integer, but are being interpreted as hex when we're trying to convert to string.

e.g.

```
> 0123.to_s
=> 83
```

Is there a way of treating the value as an integer, even though it's in a format that Ruby sees as hex. If there isn't we'll just change the database field to varchar!

Comment: I don't understand how the database comes into play here. Are you using code that pulls from a database to create Ruby code, and then running the Ruby code? I cannot imagine why you would be putting a leading zero in your Ruby code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, that's not hexadecimal, that's octal. If you don't want this behavior, don't put a leading zero on your integer literals in code:

```
irb(main):001:0> 0123         # octal literal
#=> 83

irb(main):002:0> 0x123        # hex literal
#=> 291

irb(main):003:0> 123          # base-10 literal
#=> 123

irb(main):004:0> "0123".to_i  # Converting string to int defaults to base 10
#=> 123
```

If the leading zero is appearing because you're using Ruby to create aligned Ruby code using printf, like so:

```
irb(main):008:0> "%04i" % 123
#=> "0123"
```

…then instead use spaces for padding rather than zeros:

```
irb(main):009:0> "%4i" % 123
#=> "  123"
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. We've decided to change the type in the database as MySQL would remove the 0 from 0123 when inserting a new row anyway.

Comment: @omhouse I have no idea what that means or how it relates to your question, but it sounds like you have solved your problem. If so, I'm glad for you.

Comment: Sorry, the original post should have been clearer. We have a Rails app which has a field to store a bank sort code (6 digits). We render this in the format 12-34-56 in the view as that is how sort codes are written in the UK (and possibly elsewhere). The sort code field in the database is of type int. When converting a sortcode such as 012345 to a String, we don't end up with "012345" as Ruby (correctly) interprets it as octal. My original question was how to get around this, but changing the data type of the sortcode field solves this as it was a poorly thought out choice to make it an int!